# How to filter async pipes into Angular child components

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

**TL,DR;** I have successfully passed the output of [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) into a child component. But when the condition fails (`filter => false`), I want to pass in the previously emitted value from an Observable.

**Detail;**

Using [Selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md), I subscribe to two slices of [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store):

```
export interface AppState {
  data: string[];
  pending: boolean;  // Are we waiting for a HTTP response?
  dirty: boolean;  // Has the data been edited locally?
}
```

...although there are three slices above, this question involves only `dirty` and `data`.

The reducer has three cases:

1. `AppActions.GET_NEW_DATA:`

   - Set `pending` to `true` to update the UI.
   - Results in a HTTP request being made (via [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects)).
2. `AppActions.GET_NEW_DATA_SUCCESS:`

   - Set `pending` to `false` to update the UI.
   - Set `dirty` to `false` because no edits have been made.
3. `AppActions.EDIT_DATA:`

   - Update data provided in payload.
   - Set `dirty` to `true` because an edit has been made.

The code:

```
export function appReducer(state: AppState = initialState,
    action: AppActions.All
): AppState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AppActions.GET_NEW_DATA:
            // Action results in HTTP request.
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true
            };
        case AppActions.GET_NEW_DATA_SUCCESS:
            // HTTP response, update data!
            return {
                data: action.payload,
                pending: false,
                pristine: true,
            };
        case AppActions.EDIT_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload,
                pristine: false
            };
        default: {
          return state;
        }
     }
 }
```

As mentioned earlier, using [Selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md), I subscribe to two slices of [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) from within the *smart* component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-smart',
  templateUrl: './smart.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SmartComponent {

  public data$: Observable<string[]>;
  public dirty$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private readonly store: Store<AppState>) {
      this.data$ = this.store.select(fromReducer.getData);
      this.dirty$ = this.store.select(fromReducer.getDirty);
  }
}
```

The smart component uses [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to detect when a new value is emitted from the Observable and mark the dumb component to be checked for changes.

```
<!-- From within <app-smart> -->
<app-dumb [data]="data$|async"></app-dumb>
```

This works as expected, however, I only want  to be updated if `dirty` is `false` - i.e. when a new HTTP request is made and response received.

I don't want to redraw `<app-dumb>` when the `data$` Observable emits a change from an editing. In summary, I require the following behavior:

When creating:

- `data$` emits new value.

  - `dirty$` is `false`.
  - Mark `<app-dumb>` to be checked for changes.

When editing:

- `data$` emits new value.

  - `dirty$` is `true`.
  - Do NOT mark `<app-dumb>` to be checked for changes.

This looked like a prime case for combing Observables:

```
this.data$ = this.store
  .select(fromReducer.getData)
  .withLatestFrom(this.dirty$)
  .filter(([_, dirty]) => !dirty)
  .map(([tree, _]) => tree);
```

...breaking this down

1. `this.store.select(fromReducer.getData)` grab an Observable from [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) using [selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md).
2. Combine **newly emitted** `data$` result with **latest result** from `dirty$`.
3. Filter on whether `dirty$` is false.

   - If NOT dirty, we have new data from the server and want to update `<app-dumb>`.
   - If dirty, then an edit caused `data$` to emit a new value, and we should ignore it.

The problem is `<app-smart>` is contained within a [Material Tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview), and as such may be removed (`ngOnDestroy`) and recreated (`ngOnInit`) as the user switches tabs. See [Life Cycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

If and edit has been made, `dirty$` is true.  If the user then switches tabs and subsequently returns, `data$` is filtered out because `dirty$` is `true`:

`filter(([_, dirty]) => !dirty)`

I have successfully passed the output of [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) into the child `<app-dumb>` component. But. When the condition fails, I want to pass in the previously emitted value from `data$` - and this is where I could really do with some help.

Answer (score 0):

try to create the observable of data starting from the dirty observable something like this

```
this.data$ = this.store.select(fromReducer.getDirty)
.filter(dirty=>dirty)
.flatMap(()=>this.store.select(fromReducer. getData))
```

In that way you always going to receive new data if the filter of dirty pass